# How to add user timezone to utc date

Tags: java, jodatime

how to add user timezone to utc
i am getting utc date like this

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(getval[2]);
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Now i want to get user Timezone and add it to utc to convert that to localtime

**UPDATE**

i was able to get the user timezone but could add it to the utc

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(getval[2]);

java.util.Calendar now = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();

DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone.getID());
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
ofm.setDate(dateTimeUtc.toDateTime(dtZone).toDate());
```

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

This below code may help you to get the time zone of the user

```
//get Calendar instance
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

//get current TimeZone using getTimeZone method of Calendar class
TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();

//display current TimeZone using getDisplayName() method of TimeZone class
System.out.println("Current TimeZone is : " + timeZone.getDisplayName());
```

also the below link helps you to convert user's timezone to UTC

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082325/how-to-convert-utc-and-local-timezone-in-java)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The *Joda-Time* project was succeeded by the *java.time* framework defined in JSR 310. Here is the modern solution using those new classes found in Java 8 and later.

Your input format is nearly compliant with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The data is just missing the `T` between the date portion and the time-of-day portion, and is missing a `Z` on the end to indicate UTC. See if you can educate the publisher of your data about this important standard.

```
String input = "2019-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z" ;
```

The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

> instant.toString() = 2019-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z

If you can get the input format changed, define a formatting pattern to match.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-ddHH:mm:ss" ) ;
```

Lacking any indicator of time zone or offset, we must parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Note that such an object does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a specific point on the timeline.

```
String input = "2019-01-2301:23:45" ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString() = 2019-01-23T01:23:45

You claim to be sure this date and time were intended to represent a moment in UTC. So we can apply an offset using the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` to produce a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> odt.toString() = 2019-01-23T01:23:45Z

Then you said you want to adjust this into a specific time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but different wall-clock time.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString() = 2019-01-23T02:23:45+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

As you can see, Tunisia on that date was running an hour ahead of UTC. So the time-of-day appears to be 2 AM rather than 1 AM.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example that gets the difference from a list of time zones (in hours):

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.TimeZone;
    public class StackOverflowTimeZone {
        public static void main(String[] a) {
            Date date = new Date();
            for(int index = 0; index < TimeZone.getAvailableIDs().length; index++) {
                System.out.println(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()[index] + " offset from UTC: " + TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()[index]).getOffset(date.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 1000) + " hours.");
            }
        }
    }
```

The abstract class TimeZone was designed to get the offset of a designated time zone from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). There is a list of time zones that can be found by using the method **TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()**. After getting the offset, you will need to do a few small calculuations in order to find out whether the designated time zone is ahead or behind UTC. The sign (**+**/**-**) of your output should correlate to whether that designated time zone is ahead or behind UTC.