# Converting String hours and minutes in to UTC in java

Tags: android

I have hours and minutes in string and i want to convert it into UTC time zone below is my code but I am getting wrong hours and minutes please help me....thanks

```
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Utils.merchantTimeZone));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    System.out.println("Raw time====" + rawTime);
    time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(rawTime.substring(0, 2)));
    time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(rawTime.substring(2,4)));

    sdf.format(time);
    rawTime = time.get(Calendar.HOUR) +""+ time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: What you want and what you get?

Comment: provide error logs and input value

Comment: check joda-time android library, It has lots of ready function to convert date and time.... https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

Comment: When I am passing 0830(Asia/Calcutta) to rawTime then I got 1400 which is not a proper UTC Hour. I want proper UTC hours

Comment: is it possible to convert  23:00 (Asia/Calcutta)  to  UTC  hours

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Utils.merchantTimeZone));

`TimeZone` was replaced by `ZoneId`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ; // Or `Africa/Tunis`, `Europe/Paris`, etc.
```

The `Calendar` class was replaced by `ZonedDateTime`. Capture the current moment by calling `now`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

> SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

Better to automatically localize. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Code:

```
FormatStyle style = FormatStyle.LONG ; 
Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "IN" ) ;  // English in India.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( style ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> 26 July 2019 at 7:28:36 PM GMT-06:00

If you would rather hard-code a formatting pattern, search StackOverflow for `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`. This has been covered many times already.

> rawTime = time.get(Calendar.HOUR) +""+ time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

If you want just the time-of-day portion without the date and without the time zone, extract a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

If you want only the hour and minutes without seconds and fractional second, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) ;
```

> i want to convert it into UTC time zone

This part of your Question is unclear. If you want to adjust from a zoned moment to see that same moment in UTC, simply convert to a `OffsetDateTime` object and adjust into UTC using the `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

What's the difference between a `ZonedDateTime` with a time zone and an `OffsetDateTime` with an offset-from-UTC? An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, nothing more. A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

> When I am passing 0830(Asia/Calcutta) to rawTime then I got 1400 which is not a proper UTC Hour

Apparently you want to specify a time-of-day to a date.

First get today's date, as an example.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;           // Current date as seen in India right now.
```

Specify your time-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 8 , 30 ) ;
```

Combine all three parts to get a `ZonedDateTime`. If that time-of-day is not valid on that date in that zone, `ZonedDateTime` will adjust.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2019-07-27T08:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

To see that same moment in UTC, extract a `Instant`. The `Instant` class is always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-07-27T03:00:00Z

Notice the time-of-day. On this date, India is five and a half hours ahead of UTC. So 5.5 hours less on the time-of-day is 3 AM UTC.

> is it possible to convert 23:00 (Asia/Calcutta) to UTC hours

Yes, similar to code just above. Here we alternatively call [`ZonedDateTime::with`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with(java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster)).

```
ZonedDateTime
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) 
)
.with( 
    LocalTime.of( 23 , 0 ) 
)
.toInstant() 
.toString()
```

> 2019-07-27T17:30:00Z

Again, on this date India is five and a half hours ahead of UTC. So winding the face of a clock backwards 5.5 hours from 11 PM shows 5:30 PM.

[image: diagram of date-time types in Java (both legacy & modern) and in standard SQL]

---

The classes seen here are built into Java 8 and later, as well as Android 26 and later.

- Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.
- Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you add the following line to your code:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

As a resource, I'm looking to the following thread answer given by [Affe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331052/affe): Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082325/how-to-convert-utc-and-local-timezone-in-java)

**Edit**: <s>Class TimeZone [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html). Also, here is a very nice tutorial by Jenkov [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html)</s>

**Edit 2**: Note to the Reader: The TimeZone class is now legacy, supplanted by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) and [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html). Thanks to [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098323/converting-string-hours-and-minutes-in-to-utc-in-java/33213089#comment100961007_33213089)

Comment: Note to the Reader: The `TimeZone` class is now legacy, supplanted by `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`.